# Transferring Facebook app ownership if you don't have access to original owner account

Tags: facebook

I took over development of an app for a client and the person who setup the Facebook app gave me admin rights.   However, the person is no longer working with us and can't be reached.  This is a live app and there is also a FB ad campaign associated with the app.   How can we remove him from the app and transfer ownership to me?   There is no way to track him down and we have no access to his FB account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about Facebook admin tools. You should probably contact Facebook about this issue.

Comment: If you are admin of the app you can just remove him.